# Substituting Cells In Formula That Contains Equals And Quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following data:

```
http://example1.com    anchor text 1    
http://example2.com    anchor text 2
http://example3.com    anchor text 3
```

And I would like the output to be:

```
http://example1.com    anchor text 1    <a href="http://example1.com">anchor text 1</a>
http://example2.com    anchor text 2    <a href="http://example1.com">anchor text 2</a>
http://example3.com    anchor text 3    <a href="http://example1.com">anchor text 3</a>
```

I have tried getting the code to substitute cells A1 and B1 in cell C1 like this:

```
="<a href="A1">B1</a>"
```

However, I'm getting errors because of the equal sign and double quotes in the HTML code. I have tried using single quotes to escape it, but still no luck.

Anyone know how to do this? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use multiple quotes to tell Excel that you want to leave one in the output.

Also you need to use `&` to concatenate the string together:

```
="<a href=""" & A1 & """>" & B1 & "</a>"
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. This is perfect. Thank you for the quick help. Please support the question if you thought it was well crafted :-)